# How to test WPF components using NUnit?

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5.9

I am trying to test each components of my WPF application by using NUnit. But how to test the graphical components like button, grid, textblock, richtextbox etc?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [Teststack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White)
. 
Pretty easy to use:

1. Start application.
2. Attach app process.
3. Find Window by (SearchCriteria).
4. Get element you want to test by Window.Get(SearchCriteria)
5. Test whatever you want

[Tutorial Link](http://teststack.azurewebsites.net/White/GettingStarted.html)

Cheers

Comment: Its OK. But I want to do it in NUnit.

Comment: What do you mean by do it in nUnit? nUnit is framework that just allow assertions.